# zK learning, don't know where to start

Tags: zksnark, zero-knowledge, zksync

I am thinking of learning zK (don't know where to start).
If someone with experience could point to the best resources to learn starting from 0, that would be awesome.

It exists already advanced knowledge of solidity/ethers/hardhat/foundry

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here is my list of recommendations. I have summarized it because in my experience, people don't look at everything if there is too much to look for. So I'll give you the best of the best (IMO):

## Video format

The guys who talk about it the best for me are Dan Boneh, Alessandro Chiesa, and Justin Thaler. You'll never watch enough of their videos, I'll put you the one you should see:

- Alessandro [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjkIQLJk4eQ&list=PLQxVQ1vPKm6LshS9pUxm3p1lBXaX2wQi5) on how to create SNARKs. He gives the core of what's constituting SNARKs and a bit of the associated history. He is 'general' enough to keep what he says understandable and manage to give enough details at the same time.
- Series of three videos by Dan Boneh. [This is the first one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-94UhJLeck).
- Justin Thaler explains SNARKs in detail in two parts. Here is [part one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg6lKPdR_e4).

## Paper format

- For anything related to maths, either number theory or group theory, [this site](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/number-theory/) is excellent.
- There's an [introduction to SNARKs](https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/01/26/snarks.html) by Vitalik which is quite good, especially if you need a reminder about polynomials.
- A thorough explanation paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.07221.pdf, though there are a lot of pages .

Finally, if you want a source that is sufficient without the need for other material to understand everything from A to Z concerning SNARKs, here is an excellent book on the subject, [moonmath-manual](https://leastauthority.com/community-matters/moonmath-manual/).

---

Honorable mention: this site also provides valuable links: [awesome-zkp](https://github.com/matter-labs/awesome-zero-knowledge-proofs).

Comment: i just saw this and is fits the best for first video to watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbKnVPkdMtk

Answer (score 1):

Adding the [Awesome Zero Knowledge Proofs repo](https://github.com/matter-labs/awesome-zero-knowledge-proofs) that we have in Matter Labs and has tons of resources.